# Find the smallest positive integer k such that $p^k = 1A$

Tags: permutations

Given:
$$p = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9 \\ 
 1&5  &7  &4  &6  &9  &3  &2  &8 
\end{bmatrix}$$
How would I go about determining $k$ such that:
$$p^k = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9 \\ 
 1&2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know I can continuously multiply the permutations till I reach the answer but is there a quicker or "right way" of determining the answer?

Comment: Writing $p$ in its disjoint cyclic representation, this is $(2~5~6~9~8)(3~7)$.  Look at the least common multiple of the cycle's lengths in the disjoint cyclic representation.

Comment: @JMoravitz I've added onto my question, if you wouldn't mind having a look.

Comment: You must have made some mistake in your example for $p_2$.  The image of $1$ under $(p_2)^4$ is $6$.  That should be quick to verify since the image of $1$ under $(p_2)^k$ is simply going to be the $k$'th term in the sequence (*starting count from zero*) of $1\mapsto 5\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 6\mapsto 4\mapsto 7\mapsto 8\mapsto 1\mapsto \cdots$, the first positive $k$ for which $1$ maps to itself (*and indeed all elements map to themselves for your example of $p_2$*) being $8$

Comment: See [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-order-theorem-for-permutations) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Product_of_Disjoint_Permutations) and your textbook and/or lecture notes, and many other sources.

Comment: @JMoravitz I did make a mistake indeed. I was multiplying $p^2$ by $p^2$ and then $p^4$ by $p^4$. Apologies